# CPT - Custom Text fields point to new url permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, permalinks, urls

I'm trying to set up a custom post type to be able to have custom textarea fields that I can add the full source of an HTML page to and have it be available to view at a certain url. I don't want them to be linked to other pages or subpages though. Just, if I enter HTML in a textarea - that it'll show up if I go to that certain url.

[image]

In the screenshot above, I have a custom post type called "package". I have an idea to have the content of the 3 textareas live where the urls, 'email', 'register', and 'thank-you' are. So with every package having a new url, I'd like to have the same 3 urls 'email', 'register', and 'thank-you' tagged to the end and when you visit that, whatever content is in the textareas shows up.

If anyone could help me achieve this, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Search around here for `add_rewrite_endpoint`, I've answered a similar question in the past that might help you out.

Comment: Thanks @Milo - I think I have it figured out. I appreciate your help!